# dictionary value changes as list changes in the previous recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

```
def bestSum(target, numbers, dict):
    if target in dict:
        return dict[target]
    if target == 0:
        return []
    if target < 0:
        return None

    shortestCombination = None
    for num in numbers:
         resultCombination = bestSum(target - num, numbers, dict)
         if resultCombination is not None:
             resultCombination.append(num)
             if (shortestCombination is None or len(resultCombination) < len(shortestCombination)):
                shortestCombination = resultCombination

    dict[target] = shortestCombination
    return shortestCombination

print(bestSum(8,[4,2,7],{}))
```

This should print 4,4 but it prints 4,4,2. Without memoization it works fine. When I debugged, I saw that dict is storing [2,2] for a key of 2 when it should only store[2]. I think the value is pointing to the reference of shortestCombination(which in turn points to resultCombination) but it is changing with the next recursive call although I am talking about a different shortestCombination. The change happens in the line  resultCombination.append(num)

Comment: To begin with, what is your code supposed to do ? (Like the general purpose)

Comment: `dict` is already the name of a builtin class. Please avoid at all costs naming your own variables `dict`. Call them `d` or `dictionary` or something else instead. Shadowing the name of a builtin can have unintended consequences.

Comment: The code takes in an array and target sum and returns the shortest combination of numbers from the array that sum to the target. Every number can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fixes all cases, but for the specific case you are using, it does:

```
def bestSum(target, numbers, dict):
    if target in dict:
        return dict[target]
    elif target == 0:
        return []
    elif target < 0:
        return None

    shortestCombination = None
    for num in numbers:
        resultCombination = bestSum(target - num, numbers, dict)
        if resultCombination is not None:
            resultCombination.append(num)
            if shortestCombination is None or len(resultCombination) < len(
                shortestCombination
            ):
                shortestCombination = resultCombination[:]  # Difference is here

    dict[target] = shortestCombination
    return shortestCombination
```

The only change I made was to the line: `shortestCombination = resultCombination`. I changed it to `shortestCombination = resultCombination[:]`, which sets it to a copy of the list that variable points to, which is probably what you want.

---

### Edit

I'll be honest, I'm not great at recursion. However, let me know if this fixes the problem.

Either sort the `numbers` array before passing it into the function (more efficient but doesn't look great):

```
print(bestSum(16, sorted([1, 4, 8], reverse=True), {}))
```

##### OR

Sort numbers within the function. This probably leads to a lot of overhead though so I wouldn't recommend it:

```
for num in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
```

The sorting with `reverse=True` means that the bigger numbers come first, which seems to solve the issue (from my limited testing).

Comment: So the change worked for the specific case I mentioned but when I tried it for a target of 16 with numbers as [8,4,2] I got [8,4,4] instead of [8,8]. Again when I debugged, my dict had the value for a key of 2 as [2,2] and not [2]. As soon as resultCombination changed, the dict value for 2 changed.

Comment: for(int num : numbers) {
         int rem = target - num;
         List<Integer> result = bestSum1(rem, numbers, memo);
         if(result != null) {
            List<Integer> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(result);
            newCombination.add(num);
            if(shortest == null || newCombination.size() < shortest.size()) {
               shortest = newCombination;
            }
         }
      }

Comment: This is a bit of a complex problem, I'll have a look when I have some more time on my hands, but include the goal of your code in the question itself and this fix  that hasn't fully solved your issue, in case someone else wants to come along and help out.

Comment: Edited, let me know if that's of any help